# firebase retrieving value not correct

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem retrieving a value in Firebase. I added a `TextView` to see the value inside a datasnapshot and Im seeing it correctly but when Im adding it in my `ListView` it looks like this. Btw, my `ListView` is the green one.

[image]

In my `TextView` the value is correct but in my listview its like that. Here my code for retrieving values.

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
    ref.child("Sold").child("Item").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                //textView.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
                    Product value = child.getValue(Product.class);
                    products.add(value);
                    textView.setText(value.getDescription() + " - " + child.getValue());
                }
                productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }catch (Exception e)
            {

                textView.setText(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

productAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, products);
    listViewProducts.setAdapter(productAdapter);
```

This is my Product class

```
class Product {
private String Description;
private int Qty;

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}

public int getQty() {
    return Qty;
}

public void setQty(int qty) {
    Qty = qty;
}

public Product(String description, int qty) {

    Description = description;
    Qty = qty;
}

public Product(){}
```

}

Comment: try implementing toString in your Product class

Comment: @Solace I added my product class in the question. Where should I put the toString()?

Comment: Inside the Product class. Return a String that you want to represent a Product, and that should be what you see for each product in your ListView

Comment: @Solace its still the same :(

Comment: @Mark you are setting whole object to the textview of the list at this line ->  products.add(value);  if you want to pass class in adapter you should go with viewHolder approach or change this products.add(value) to products(value.getDescription()) etc

Comment: try to override toString method in your model class

Comment: @SaraTirmizi Yes im passing the whole data to my textview just to check for the value if its correct. My problem is in the listview its not showing correctly. It is showing my project name plus the Product class and some number which I dont know. The data im suppose to get from firebase is "Description: Mark Stephen Dumm 1" and "Qty: 99" and put them in my listview

Comment: @Mark I am saying you are passing object Product to the listview item android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 which is a textview that is why it is showing you the class name, you need to add string in products.add() line before calling  notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: @SaraTirmizi its working now but its only showing my description how to achieve to get both data description and qty? Thanks for the help

Comment: For example do this -> add these lines in for loop String txtValue = value.getDescription() + " - " + child.getValue() ; products.add(txtValue) and remove line products.add(value) and now run your code

Comment: @SaraTirmizi Ohhh its working now thank you so much ive been stuck in this since yesterday thank you again

Comment: You're welcome but @Mark it is not the correct way to achieve that If you have complex class and custom list views. check following for future reference. https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-and-viewholder/

Comment: @SaraTirmizi Do you know how to add the value.getDescription to a sub item?

Comment: @Mark for that you need custom adapters .. try searching for adapter and view holders to get better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are getting in your `LisView` is basically the String representation of your `Product` object. So the following string:

```
 com.example.mark.mobilethesis.Product@e8e0966
```

Actually represents the address of the `Product` object from the memory, which certainly isn't what you want. To display both data, `description` and `qty` you have three options.

The first one and the simplest one would be to override `toString()` method in your `Product` class, as was also suggested by the other users. This should look like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return description + " / " + qty;
}
```

The second option would be to change the type of your list from `Product` to `String` like this:

```
for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
    List<String> products = new ArrayList<>();
    Product value = child.getValue(Product.class);
    products.add(value.getDescription() + " / " + child.getValue());
}

ArrayAdapter<String> productAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    getApplicationContext(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    products
);
listViewProducts.setAdapter(productAdapter);
```

The thirt one would be the create a custom adapter. So even if you are passing the whole `Product` object to the adapter, you can get only the `description` and `qty` inside the adapter.

Comment: Hi Mark! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Problem was solved. I did a custom adapter and it works now. Thank you